# How to set WKWebviewConfiguration for a xamarin forms webview?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview, xamarin.forms.webview

I have a Xamarin forms project where I need to set certain configurations for allowing file access. In native xamarin ios project, it was set through the WKWebviewConfiguration like,

```
_scormWKPreferences = new WKPreferences
            {
                JavaScriptEnabled = true
            };
            ClearCookies();
            _scormWKPreferences.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject(true), (NSString)"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs");
            //  _scormWKPreferences.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject(true), (NSString)"allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs");
            _scormWKWebconfiguration = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
            _scormWKWebconfiguration.Preferences = _scormWKPreferences;
            _scormWKUserContentController = new WKUserContentController();
            _scormWKUserContentController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, WKSCRIPT_HANDLER);
            _scormWKWebconfiguration.UserContentController = _scormWKUserContentController;
            CGRect viewRect = new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height);
            _courseWKWebview = new WKWebView(viewRect, _scormWKWebconfiguration);
```

I have to achieve the same in the forms project as well. Currently, I have added a Custom Renderer in the iOS module but not able to set the configuration. Please find the CustomRenderer below.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(ScholarApp.Droid.Reader.Scorm.ScormCustomRenderer))]
namespace ScholarApp.Droid.Reader.Scorm
{
    public class ScormCustomRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WkWebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement == null && e.NewElement != null)
            {
                WKPreferences wkPreferences = new WKPreferences
                {
                    JavaScriptEnabled = true
                };
                wkPreferences.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject(true), (NSString)"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs");
                WKWebViewConfiguration wkConfig = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                wkConfig.Preferences = wkPreferences;
                WKWebView wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, wkConfig);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I set this configuration to my WebView?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean about *not able to load the local content into the WKWebview* .You can show more code about  meaning of local content .

Answer (score 3):

Also you may try to pass the configuration via the parametrized `WkWebViewRenderer` constructor

```
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
{
    static WKWebViewConfiguration CreateConfiguration() => new WKWebViewConfiguration
    {
        Preferences = new WKPreferences
        {
            JavaScriptEnabled = true
        }
    };

    public CustomWebViewRenderer() : base(CreateConfiguration()) { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked very good for latest version of iOS.

Comment: @acido glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt your renderer:

```
 public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<WebView, WKWebView>
    {
        WKWebView _wkWebView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                WKPreferences wkPreferences = new WKPreferences
            {
                JavaScriptEnabled = true
            };
            wkPreferences.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject(true), (NSString)"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs");
            WKWebViewConfiguration wkConfig = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
            wkConfig.Preferences = wkPreferences;
                _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Source as UrlWebViewSource).Url)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without using the WKWebView am able to load the local file from documents folder into the Forms WebView but the moment I add the custom renderer and the corresponding code am not able to load the local content into the WKWebview.

Comment: Well, that is a different problem. Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: No not getting any exception